# Parse a big file and populate a Neo4j database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neography

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project that will read and parse somewhat big text file (around 100k lines) and build Neo4j nodes (I am using [Neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/)) with that data.
This is the Neo4j related fraction of the code I wrote:

```
    d= Neography::Rest.new.execute_query("MATCH (n:`Label`) WHERE (n.`name`='#{id}') RETURN n")
    d= Neography::Node.load(d, @neo)
    p= Neography::Rest.new.create_node("name" => "#{id}") 
    Neography::Rest.new.add_label(p, "LabelSample") 
    d=Neography::Rest.new.get_node(d)
    Neography::Rest.new.create_relationship("belongs_to", p, d)
```

so, what I want to do is: a search in the already populated db for the node with the same "name" field as the parsed data, create a new node for this data and finally create a relationship between the two of them.
Obiously this code simply takes way too much time to be executed.
So I tried with Neography's batch, but I ran into some issues.

```
    p = Neography::Rest.new.batch [:create_node, {"name" => "#{id}"}]
```

gave me a "undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass" in

id["self"].split('/').last

```
    d=Neography::Rest.new.batch [:get_node, d]
```

gives me a Neography::UnknownBatchOptionException for get_node

I am not even sure this will save me enough time either.

I also tried different ways to do this, using [Batch Import](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) for example, but I couldn't find a way to get the already created node I need from the db.
As you can see I'm kinda new to this so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with pure cypher (or neography generated cypher).  Something like this perhaps:

```
MATCH (n:Label) WHERE n.name={id}
WITH n
CREATE (p:LabelSample {name: n.name})-[:belongs_to]->n
```

Not that I'm using CREATE, but if you don't want to create duplicate `LabelSample` nodes you could do:

```
MATCH (n:Label) WHERE n.name={id}
WITH n
MERGE (p:LabelSample {name: n.name})
CREATE p-[:belongs_to]->n
```

Note that I'm using params, which are generally recommended for performance (though this is just one query, so it's not as big of a deal)

Comment: Thanks Brian, I gave it a try and the performance is noticeably better, but it still took around 25 minutes (down from "it has been 80 minutes, I give up" from my former code) to process my 80k rows long sample dataset. Is there a way to improve anymore the performance?

Comment: @AGarofoli You'll get a huge performance boost from params if you're doing that same query over and over again, check out http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html and replace the `{name: n.name}` with a param. You can also consider doing chunks of your updates in transactions that you close every X number of items. It'll give you another little boost, though I'm not sure how you'd do that with Neography.